# Django ошибка запуска сервера

Tags: python, django

При запуске сервера получаю ошибку[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Накануне копировала всю папку проекта.
Это запуск из базового места

---

> Попробуйте указать версию питона при запуске

Добавила версию питона - стало больше ошибок
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Попробуйте указать версию питона при запуске

Comment: Добавила версию питона - ошибок стало больше
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in main
    from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
ImportError: No module named 'django'
The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 16, in main
    ) from exc
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable?

Comment: Повторная установка Djangoв проект ничего не изменила

Comment: Вы уверены, что устанавливали `Django` именно в `virtualenv`? Приведите, пожалуйста, инструкцию, которую для этого исполняли.

Comment: (virtualenv) darya@samsung:~/Work/Python-back/TestRiz$ pip install django

Comment: Откуда куда вы ее копировали?

Answer (score 0):

Решение оказалось простым, хотя такого варианта я не нашла ни в одном чате.

Необходимо выйти из текущего virtualenv и удалить его папку. А затем создать виртуальную среду заново с учётом версий используемых в проекте пакетов.

Вот и всё!Всем спасибо)